# Mysql: "where in" but need duplicates too

Tags: mysql

I have several items id to query, even if they are several ones. I explain:

I have a table `id | item`
I have some ids to query (eg. 25, 62, 89, 123, 12, 25, 25, 62)
I need to display all of them, even if there is several times the same id, without having to make several queries. If I use the "`where in`" query, it groups the ids, so display only once id 25 for example...

How can I manage to do that please?

My query:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link,"select p.id_product, p.price, c.link_rewrite as catrew, i.id_image, l.link_rewrite, l.name, s.reduction, s.reduction_type
    from rec_product p
    left join rec_image i on i.id_product=p.id_product and i.cover=1
    left join rec_product_lang l on l.id_product=p.id_product and l.id_lang = 1
    left join rec_category_lang c on c.id_category=p.id_category_default
    left join rec_specific_price s on s.id_product=p.id_product
    WHERE p.id_product IN ($id_prod_array)
    order by rand()");
```

**Example**:

```
$id_prod_array = "13,13,119";
```

**Result**:

[image]

**expected**:
2 times the first one (id 13) and one time the id 119 one

[edit]

Found the solution: example with id 13,13,119

```
select p.id_product, p.price, c.link_rewrite as catrew, i.id_image, l.link_rewrite, l.name, s.reduction, s.reduction_type
        from rec_product p
        join (select 13 as id_product
              union all select 13
              union all select 119) as T1 on p.id_product = T1.id_product
        left join rec_image i on i.id_product=p.id_product and i.cover=1
        left join rec_product_lang l on l.id_product=p.id_product and l.id_lang = 1
        left join rec_category_lang c on c.id_category=p.id_category_default and c.id_lang = 1
        left join rec_specific_price s on s.id_product=p.id_product
```

Comment: Can you post your query?

Comment: Please, post your data sample and how desired output should look like

Comment: If you want `13`, `13`, `119` in result, you should make it group with some other column. I.e `group by id_product, someOtheCol`

Answer (score 1):

You need `FIND_IN_SET` function to search values of `$id_prod_array`.

Change:

```
WHERE p.id_product IN ($id_prod_array)
```

To:

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET( p.id_product, REPLACE( $id_prod_array, ' ', '' ) ) > 0
```

And it should be working.

---

Reasons for why your query did not work is analysed as below:

If

```
 `$id_prod_array` = '25, 62, 89, 123, 12, 25, 25, 62'
```

Then don't *assume* that when used with sql `IN`, it is equivalent to:

```
WHERE p.id_product IN ( 25, 62, 89, 123, 12, 25, 25, 62 )
```

but, it is equivalent to:

```
WHERE p.id_product IN ( '25, 62, 89, 123, 12, 25, 25, 62' )
```

Meaning: both are not equal for interpretation by `IN`

```
'25, 62, 89, 123, 12, 25, 25, 62' != 25, 62, 89, 123, 12, 25, 25, 62
```

***Example***:

```
mysql> select 89 in ( 25, 62, 89, 123, 12, 25, 25, 62 );
+-------------------------------------------+
| 89 in ( 25, 62, 89, 123, 12, 25, 25, 62 ) |
+-------------------------------------------+
|                                         1 |
+-------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.08 sec)

mysql> select 89 in ( '25, 62, 89, 123, 12, 25, 25, 62' );
+---------------------------------------------+
| 89 in ( '25, 62, 89, 123, 12, 25, 25, 62' ) |
+---------------------------------------------+
|                                           0 |
+---------------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.04 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                  |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------|
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE               |
|         |      | value: '25, 62, 89, 123, 12, 25, 25, 62' |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------+
```

***Refer to***:

- [MySQL: FIND_IN_SET(str,strlist)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Comment: Doesn't work with `WHERE FIND_IN_SET( p.id_product, $id_prod_array ) > 0`
Returns blank result

Comment: Check once with test data like, if `p.id_product` is `89` then, `WHERE FIND_IN_SET( 89, '25, 62, 89, 123, 12, 25, 25, 62' )` and see if you can get results.

Comment: Check my update with correction. I removed *spaces* in the CSV string.

Comment: `WHERE FIND_IN_SET( 89, REPLACE( '25, 62, 89, 123, 12, 25, 25, 62', ' ', '' ) )`

Comment: with `WHERE FIND_IN_SET( 89, '25, 62, 89, 123, 12, 25, 25, 62' )` it returns all the rows of the table. With your correction it returns blank result...

Comment: With `WHERE FIND_IN_SET( 89, REPLACE( '25, 62, 89, 123, 12, 25, 25, 62', ' ', '' ) )` returns all the rows of the table

Comment: Follow the changes made using `REPLACE` and `> 0` is a must.

Comment: Returns blank result... :-(

Comment: Did you check with output for a given product id and search string?

Comment: Blank means what? `Empty set`? No data found?

Comment: `Did you check with output for a given product id and search string?` Yes

Comment: You better add to your post, the following: 1. sample records with `p.id_product`, 2. The way how you are generating value for `$id_prod_array`, and 3. expected result for a given `id_product` value.

Comment: If you want `13`, `13`, `119` in result, you should make it group with some other column. I.e `group by id_product, someOtheCol`.

Comment: I tried with `group by p.id_product,i.id_image` but it returns id 13 and 119 only one time

Comment: Group should be unique to return duplicate values on id_product. I fear, you have only `13 - 55` group on `id_prod - image` for `id_prod=13`. And hence the unique result.

Comment: I can do a union all and duplicate all query (one per id_product returned in $id_prod_array), but I'm afraid it can be heavy for mysql server?...